# What is this dashed line called that aligns function blocks in my IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, code-organization

The SPE IDE that I use for my Python code uses this "visual cue" that looks like a vertical dashed line for alignment of (what I would call) function blocks.  How can I get this option in Visual Studio 2008?

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: No problem.  A picture paints a thousand words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen it called structural highlighting or code outlining.

There's a Visual Studio plug-in called [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) from Developer Express that [supports this](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/Visualization.xml) (bottom of the page) and a lot more.

**update:**

As divo mentioned, there is a [free lite version of CodeRush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/dd218053.aspx).  I confirmed that it includes structural highlighting.

Comment: Please note that there is a free edition for C# (and maybe VB, haven't checked it) available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/dd218053.aspx

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need -- Coderush Xpress Structural Highlighting.  Thanks!!

Comment: Installed.  Confirmed - This is exactly what I needed.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio does not support indentation lines out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Are there any third party plug-ins that add this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

These lines are arguably more useful in Python where indentation denotes nesting.  In C#, nesting is explicitly marked by curly braces.  I feel as though curly braces provide the visual cues I need to see this kind of thing, so you might just try to persevere -- in time the cognitive load associated with glimpses of C# versus glimpses of Python will reach equilibrium.

VS2010 implements the text editor in WPF and there are some examples online of creating plug-ins that augment the text editor area.  This could be a fun project without being too difficult.

I am envious of Python's indentation-centric nesting.  I wish that the C# compiler supported something like that.  I wish that white space was part of the language.  It would make tooling support for the language better as well.

Comment: Drew, your assessment seems spot on.  However, for some reason, the curly braces throw me off.  I feel like I'm constantly trying to figure out where a block of code starts and ends.  This could be because I'm relatively new to programming in general.  I definitely feel like Python's use of whitespace and indentation makes it much easier to read in comparison to C#'s curly braces.