# Visual Studio dots showing brace connection ( similar to sublime )

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sublimetext2

I write C#, UnrealScript and C++. I do C++ and C# in Visual Studio 2012, while I do UnrealScript in Sublime 2 with UnrealScript IDE plugin

In Sublime 2 there is a cool effect that shows the line connection between the open and close braces as shown in the image:

[image]

( Note: I'm not talking about the underlining of the braces - VS already has that feature. I'm referring to the dotted lines )

I can't find a way to have this in Visual Studio, the closest so far is Show White Space which while is OK, I don't like it that much. Is there a way I can have this feature? Plugin or otherwise?

Comment: Visual Studio does not support it out of the box.

also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448843/what-is-this-dashed-line-called-that-aligns-function-blocks-in-my-ide/1448879#1448879

Answer (score 1):

Try installing a free version of DevExpress Plugin for Visual Studio. Its got all those designes....